# Return exact match from content in a file using PowerShell or batch

Tags: powershell, batch

This is my powershell script:

```
$Apache_port = Get-Content -Path C:\tmp\httpd.conf | Select-String -Pattern 'Listen'
echo $Apache_port
```

But I am getting result like this:

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8020
```

But I want `8020` to print only this line, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PowerShell approach using `where-object`, `-match`, `-notmatch`, and `split()`.

This omits lines with the hashtag/pound symbol `#`, splits on the default space, and returns the second index value which is just the number. As in "`Listen<space><PortNumber>`" where 'Listen' is the first index `[0]` and the port number is the second index which you want `[1]`.

### PowerShell

```
(Get-Content -Path C:\tmp\httpd.conf | Where-Object {$_ -match "Listen" -and $_ -notmatch "#"}).Split()[1];
```

**Output**

```
8020
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

  > Filter input from the pipeline, control which objects will be passed along the command pipeline.
- [About Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)

  > `-match` - string matches regex pattern
  >
  > `-notmatch` - string does not match regex pattern
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

  > **Key**
  >
  > `strSeparator`  The character used to split up each string, by
  > default whitespace (space/newline/tab)

Comment: It is working well.!!

Comment: @anand8398 Feel free to check the gray check mark to the left side of the answer to accept it and turn it green too since you say it worked for your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$Apache_port = Get-Content -Path C:\tmp\httpd.conf | Select-String -Pattern '8020'
$Apache_port = $Apache_port -Replace "Listen ",""
echo $Apache_port
```